# CPPointOfInterestTemplate without details dialog

Tags: ios, swift, carplay

I want to use CPPointOfInterestTemplate but without details dialog after click item.

I have tried pass nils when creating poi:

```
let poi = CPPointOfInterest(location: location, title: name, subtitle: "subtitle", summary: "choose me", detailTitle: nil, detailSubtitle: nil, detailSummary: nil, pinImage: pinImage)
```

and also create pointOfInterestDelegate with implement

```
func pointOfInterestTemplate(_ pointOfInterestTemplate: CPPointOfInterestTemplate, didSelectPointOfInterest pointOfInterest: CPPointOfInterest) {
    cpInterface!.pushTemplate(createCarPlayListScreen(cpInterface: cpInterface!), animated: true)
}
```

Now after click item app does what I need, but after go back to poiTemplate I see unwanted dialog on top.

Can I do this in better way?